# Getting a PHP configuration variable in Go

Tags: php, go

I want to get the output of the command `php -r 'echo get_cfg_var("some_var");'` to check it against a predefined value. Currently, I have the following code:

```
variableName := "default_mimetype"
cmd := exec.Command("php", "-r", "'echo get_cfg_var(\"" + variableName + "\");'")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

after running,

`err.Error()` returns `"exit status 254"`

`out` is `"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1"`

What is causing this error? Am I not escaping something properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your argument. If you change what you have written into a shell command, it would look like the following:

```
$ php -r "'echo get_cfg_var(\"default_mimetype\");'"
```

You will notice that there is an extra set of quotes around the 2nd argument that is causing the syntax error. You can fix this by changing your `exec.Command` to the following:

```
cmd := exec.Command("php", "-r", "echo get_cfg_var(\"" + variableName + "\");")
```

Comment: Interesting, that's really not mentioned in the documentation that it adds quotes like that.

Comment: @Langston: `exec.Command` operates like exec*(3), not system(3).

Comment: @Langston: nothing added any quotes, you put the quotes yourself in the string literal.

Comment: @JimB Perhaps I'm confused but from Tim's answer, it appears that an extra set of double quotes gets addded around the value of the third parameter of `exec.Command`, which has no escaped quotes surrounding it initially.

Comment: @Langston no extra quotes are being added. If you do `exec.Command("cmd", "arg one here", "second thing", "single")` the command will be executed with three arguments (four if you count "cmd" itself) and in this example there won't be a quote to be seen. Manually doing this via a shell would be `cmd "arg one here" "second thing" single`, **or** `cmd arg\ one\ here second\ thing single`, **or** `cmd 'arg one here' 'second thing' "single"`, etc, etc. In other words the quotes in Tim's first example were added by him just to show that everything is being grouped together as a single argument.

Comment: @Langston in other words, you appear to have added extraneous single quotes in your question in order to group words into a single argument that is not needed and that get passed all the way into the command being run (where-as a shell needs those quotes to escape word breaks and strips them out).

Comment: @DaveC Thanks for clarifying! That makes a lot more sense.